# Let $p$ be an odd prime of the form $p=2^m+1$, for some positive integer $m$. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$ with $1 \le g \le p$.

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

Let $p$ be an odd prime of the form $p=2^m+1$, for some positive integer $m$. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$ with $1 \le g \le p$. How many such $g$ are there?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There are $\varphi(\varphi(p))$ primitive roots of any prime $p$.

Comment: so there would be $\varphi(2^m)$ such $g$?

Comment: Yes, which for positive $m$ is $2^{m-1}$, or equivalently $\frac{p-1}{2}$. For our particular case, we do not have to know the $\varphi(\varphi(p))$ fact. One can show dirrectly that the primitive roots are (congruent to) the odd powers of $g$.